# How to access ios media player instance when youtube video is playing

Tags: ios, uiwebview, youtube, media-player, mpmediaplayercontroller

I used below function for play youtube videos in iPhone using UIWebView

```
      - (void)embedYouTube {

       videoHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
             <html>\
             <head>\
             <style type=\"text/css\">\
             iframe {position:absolute; top:50%%; margin-top:-130px;}\
             body {background-color:#000; margin:0;}\
             </style>\
             </head>\
             <body>\
             <iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxxxxxxxx\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>\
             </body>\
             </html>"];

        [videoView loadHTMLString:videoHTML baseURL:nil];
    }
```

By this method video will play in the iOS media player. I wanted to hide controllers automatically, when the video is playing. Problem is how to access the media player instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can try Subview concept, to access MoviePlayercontroller. Please refer this article [here](https://gist.github.com/2308668).

Comment: now, I think it does not work any more. Maybe MoviePlayercontroller is no longer in the uiwebview